# send schedule sms in android

Tags: android

hii,

I have set alarm for sending sms and its works but when there are more than one alarm set sending sms method create problem as it start looping and giving error and i am using SMS Manager for sending messages

plz give me solution for this as i am facing many problem for this.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Agree with TOX1C. You can do the same by using AlarmManager.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Bundle bnd1=new Bundle();
    bnd1.putString("Contacts", Selected_Conta.toString());
    bnd1.putString("Message", Messa);
    selectedDate.set(syear, smonth, sday, mHour, mMinute,0);
    Intent in=new Intent(ScheduleSMS.this,SMSReceiver.class);
    in.putExtras(bnd1);
    in.setAction(ACTION_SCHEDULE_SMS);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,Request code, in, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,selectedDate.getTimeInMillis(),sender)
```

Now in receiver you'll get this bundle at schedule time so just send message from there.